# Custom iterator out of bounds

Tags: c++, iterator, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an iterator class. Let's call it `PIterator` here. A `MessageBuffer` is iterated and is being outputted correctly, unless the `nSizeOfMessage` plus where the iterator currently points to is equal to the size of the whole message (position correct, index one too large).

If I check for the last element and decrement by one, it should work. Though it seems to be a "wrong way" to me. Yeah, I am not quite sure on this, so my problem is shown in this code snippet, maybe someone knows a good solution, tried to figure it out for quite a while.

Yes, I do know how to use a debugger, I know where the problem lies and it is explained just fine. I do not know how to fix this, unless used the way I mentioned.

This compiles fine under Visual Studio 2015.

Please also see the comments in the main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MessageBuffer
{
public:
    MessageBuffer(const std::string &s)
    {
        _msgBuffer.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
    }

    char &operator[](std::size_t nIndex)
    {
        return _msgBuffer[nIndex];
    }

    //more functions...

private:
    std::vector<char> _msgBuffer;
};

class PIterator
{
public:
    PIterator(MessageBuffer &b)
        : m_Ref(b)
        , m_Where(0)
    { }

    PIterator &operator=(PIterator &other)
    {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        this->m_Ref = other.m_Ref;
        this->m_Where = other.m_Where;
        return *this;
    }

    //more functions...

    PIterator operator+(unsigned int nValue) const
    {
        PIterator copy(*this);
        copy.m_Where += nValue;
        return copy;
    }

    PIterator &operator+=(unsigned int nValue)
    {
        m_Where += nValue;
        return *this;
    }

    char &operator*()
    {
        return m_Ref[m_Where];
    }

private:
    MessageBuffer &m_Ref;
    std::size_t m_Where;
};

int wmain(int argv, wchar_t **args)
{
    std::string msg = "123MyMessage"; //Length 12
                                    //                    ^ Index 3, Position 4

    MessageBuffer mb(msg);

    PIterator itr(mb);

    //Calculations - here the results hardcoded
    std::size_t nSizeOfMessage = 9; //The size of the message without the numbers

                                    //itr.m_Where is 3 - That's where the non-numeric part of the message starts
    itr += 3;

    std::string needThis;

    PIterator cpy = itr + nSizeOfMessage; //itr points to the first element of the message
                                        //cpy is now out of bounds - position is correct, but index is 1 too large

    needThis.assign(&*itr, &*cpy); //boom

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't such a case to step through your code with the debugger, rather than asking here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ **I did that, still I came here asking for help.** Do you want me to list everything I have done and tried ? Thank you for that comment.

Comment: "*Do you want me to list everything I have done and tried ?*" - Yes, of course!

Comment: And one last thing: Describe the problem in the prose, as well as marking it in the code. It makes it easier to find (people don't have to scroll through your code to find main, they just look at the text).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Well, you might want to take 5 seconds of your time and scroll through the code, it is marked. Could you help me with this problem or do you just comment what I could improve ?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I'd have posted it. I'm trying to help you make your question better so that, when someone who can comes along, they will answer it. Generally, the easier you make it to see the problem, the more willing people will be to help.

Comment: In this particular case, knowing the implementation of `operator++()` and `operator==`/`operator!=` would be handy.

Comment: You're dereferencing `cpy` which, in iterator parlance, points to `::end()`, which is undefined behaviour. In this particular case you're trying to access a 1-past-the-end element of a vector, which throws an exception

Comment: There isn't a single question mark in your question, which begs the question *"what is the question?"*

Comment: @SteveLorimer It's pretty obvious that the index is invalid, and also that an exception is thrown. Please read the comments in the code.

Comment: @md5i The usual implementation of a pre- & post-increment operator (increment `m_Where`), nothing wrong there and not used here. The other two operators are not implemented, as they're not used and not needed in the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
needThis.assign(&*itr, &*cpy);
```

you need to use

```
needThis.assign(itr, cpy);
```

This will work if your **PIterator** satisfies iterator requirements.

The way you call **assign**, you pass pointers instead of iterators, which is valid by itself. But, to get the pointers, you dereference the iterators first. Dereferencing past-the-end iterator is undefined behavior, which is caught in Debug configuration of the compiler.

Comment: I don't implement a `std::iterator`. You can see - aside from a few missing functions and different names in the original  code - the exact implementation of the class `PIterator`. Thus using the char pointers is correct in my case. (Unless you have a special `std::string` class) My problem seems - and probably is - easy to fix. Though I do not seem to be able to fix it for every case the code is executed. I can provide more detailed information if necessary, the code in the question is to show and also explain the problem. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was quite simple.
Instead of having a temporary iterator, I'll be using the char pointer and increment it's address by the size of the message, thus receiving always the correct last element. *Should've seen that earlier.*

```
needThis.assign(&*itr, (&*itr) + nSizeOfMessage);
```